# Add control to existing custom validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have the following problem:
My ASP code is the next:

```
<span class="required">*</span> <%=LabelsFactory.Current.Get("FormLabels", "RequiredFields")%><asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" CssClass="required" DisplayMode="BulletList" ForeColor="" /><asp:CustomValidator ID="cvGeneralError" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" Display="None" ErrorMessage='<%# LabelsFactory.Current.Get("FormLabels", "GeneralError") %>'></asp:CustomValidator><asp:Panel ID="pFormElements" runat="server"></asp:Panel><asp:Panel ID="pValidators" runat="server"></asp:Panel><fieldset><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" OnClick="Button1_Click" CssClass="button" /></fieldset>
```

So in the code behind I get the info from a CMS and with this information I create the controls and added to the page.
The problem is that I need to include a control in the page into the validations if other field is filled. So once the button is clicked and the fields I want is filled I find the Control (dropdawn control) and I create a requiredFieldValidatos but in the last sentence the code crash with an Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Control myStateList = FindControl(formControl.ID + "_statelist");RequiredFieldValidator val = new RequiredFieldValidator();val.ID = "stateListValidator";val.ErrorMessage = "The field 'Select your state' is required";val.ControlToValidate = myStateList.ID;val.ValidationGroup = "ValidationGroup1";val.Validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have master page, you need to access the parent at first, which is the placeholder, then you can find the control :

```
ContentPlaceHolder cph =(ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("MainContent");
var control = (DropDownList)cph.FindControl("ddlList");
```